# How do I write a Java program that can get the time between my keyboard key-presses?

Tags: java, random

So my main objective is to create a new Random number generating function that will generate a random number with the help of human randomness. 
I want to be able to get the time between previous keystrokes that were entered by the user and save them in some sort of a float or double variable.

While trying to create such a program, I thought about using a pointer to get the address of a variable since the address is random and thought I could proceed with that. But apparently Java doesn't support pointers so here I am, trying to get a new idea for generating random numbers.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Perhaps adding the code to your question and showing where the problem is will help. Also explain what is "a variable that is random every time".

Comment: @RealSkeptic Fixed. I meant using the address since the address of a variable is random when it is declared. Regardless, since Java doesn't have pointers and I haven't found any way to get the memory address of any variable in Java, unlike C, this method wouldn't work. I have no code to show since the problem itself is- "Where do I begin?" I would like to know what I can do to get the time between keystrokes and implement it in a Java program.

Comment: Is this a command line program or do you have some sort of UI such as a `JTextField` or something?

Comment: Is there any reason that system time is not a sufficient seed for your randomization needs?

Comment: @KorayTugay It's a command line program.

Comment: @arcadeblast77 None specifically, I just thought I should create two kinds of programs, one that uses the user as the randomization factor (thus creating possibilities for more randomness as humans can be truly random), and one that doesn't (thus making a more convinent, no-effort-by-the-user program).

Comment: I truly do not believe that this will result in something "more random" than already built-in methods that just use system time for the seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will accept ENTER key to be pressed five times and keep intervals for you:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double[] randomIntervals = new double[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  scanner.nextLine();
  long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
  randomIntervals[i] = end - start;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomIntervals));
scanner.close();
```

Here is a sample run for me:

```
[1307.0, 523.0, 660.0, 165.0, 165.0]
```

Does this help?

Comment: Very much so. Thanks. I just started with Java so I was not aware of the currentTimeMillis function. That can be used for my program for sure. Thank you again.